# JSF with Spring boot 2.5+

Tags: spring-boot, jsf-2

I'm needing to get JSF running with Spring boot 2.5+ and I'm not finding an easy way to convert from a web.xml/faces-config.xml setup to the Spring Boot method.  Does anyone know of a tutorial on how to get mojarra up and running with Spring boot 2.5? I'm currently running a Spring Framework (xml) war project, that I'm trying to migrate to Spring Boot.

I don't want to use something like joinfaces (https://github.com/joinfaces/joinfaces) as I feel like it is doing too much and more then I need or want.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exact issues are you facing?

Comment: I was finally able to get it to work with the following tutorial:  https://auth0.com/blog/developing-jsf-applications-with-spring-boot/